# Managing URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to manage my url in codeigniter...
where my frontend should be like this
`"http://www.Himalayi.com/"` and the 
admin panel should be `http://www.Himalayi.com/__admin`

I am not able to manage though i've tried alot.. 
the folder structure is given below
Please
Help me.. Thanks

**application/**

```
controller/admin/home_banner.php,user.php

model/admin/model_home_banner.php, model_user.php

view/admin/home_banner/add.php
```

and

in the same folder controller i have 
frontend folder the file is `welcome.php!`

how to manage in `config, routes, htaccess`

Comment: can`t you write directly in routes.php like this  $route['__admin']  ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you would want to prepend underscores to access the admin panel. Please keep in mind that defining controller functions like:

```
public function _notReachable(){
    #do something
}
```

will result in an inaccessible function regarding web requests.
So calling example.com/home/_notReachable will not work. 
Maybe that already solves your problem?

See codeigniter documentation ["Controllers - private Functions"](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private).